# How to make git submodule files available in parent repo?

Tags: git, github

I have this directory structure:

```
--/home/user/main_git_project
  --main_files.txt
  --sub_git_project
      --sub_files.txt
```

I added the submodule with `git submodule add <url> sub_git_project`.

This created the `/home/user/main_git_project/.gitmodules` file successfully.

However, now when I `git push` the main git project and view the files at github the `sub_git_project` directory appears to be some type of symlink or placeholder (it is empty). There is no way to view or list the files in `sub_git_project`.

How can I add the `sub_git_project` to the `main_git_project` and have the sub_files be available?

Comment: After the steps you've done, I normally then call `git submodule sync` followed by `git submodule init` and finally `git submodule update` and then all my submodule files are visible in my sandbox. `git submodule --help` explains what each of these commands do.

Comment: Unfortunately, no change after ```sync```, ```init```, ```update```. As a test I cloned the ```main_git_project``` and the ```sub_git_project``` directory is still empty.

Comment: What is the `<url>` of the subrepo ? the https url of a public github repo ? of a private repo ? of a repo hosted somewhere else ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Consider the following directory structure:

```
/home/<username>/<main-git-project>
  .gitignore
  .gitmodules
  ...<main-git-project> files
  <submodule-git-project>
    .gitignore
    ...<submodule-git-project> files
```

What I first attempted was to add the `<submodule-git-project>` submodule to my `<main-git-project>`, yielding the following `.gitmodules` file:

```
[submodule "<submodule-git-project>"]
  path = <submodule-git-project>
  url = ./<submodule-git-project>
```

I committed the changes in the `<main-git-project>` and pushed them to the remote `GitHub` repository. What happened is that the `<submodule-git-project>` folder was not clickable, thus not able to view any of its contents.

What I did to resolve the issue was to create a separate `GitHub` repository for the `<submodule-git-project>`, add the remote to the submodule, push the submodule code into this new repository, and edit the `<main-git-project>`'s `.gitmodules` file so the `url` now points to the remote submodule repository.

```
[submodule "<submodule-git-project>"]
    path = <submodule-git-project>
    url = https://github.com/<github-username>/<submodule-git-project>.git
```

Now the `<main-git-project>`'s `GitHub` repository has a hyperlink-styled `<submodule-git-project>`'s folder that redirects you to the submodule's `GitHub` repository.

[This is a sample project I have in my account so you can better appreciate what I am talking about.](https://github.com/AlejandroRodarte/course-microservices-ticketing-app)